# What type of cookies will be deleted during GC?

Tags: javascript, cookies, garbage-collection

I have set one cookie with validity one year. But it was deleted frequently. To know the cause of this, I have used an extension for cookie monitoring. That shows the cause is "evicted". The cause evicted means evicted during GC. Is there any possible workaround to prevent deleting cookies by GC?

Comment: I've never heard of garbage collection messing with cookies. Maybe you just misconfigured your browser? Notice you cannot *force* a user agent to keep cookies when the user doesn't like to.

Comment: Yeah bergi. pleae refer the following link. But cookie clear during GC is possilble

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/OnChangedCause

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of JS GC which makes no sense, and I was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it was deleted frequently, the cause is "evicted".

Yes, it was eaten by the [cookie monster](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/cookiemonster) (no, not [that one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_Monster)):

"*Garbage collection occurs when a cookie is set (this is expected to happen much less often than retrieving cookies).  Garbage collection makes sure that the number of cookies per-eTLD+1 does not exceed some maximum, and similarly for the total number of cookies.  The algorithm is both in flux and subtle; see the comments in cookie_monster.h for details.*"

When searching the web you'll find some bug reports that discuss the various tweaks to the algorithm.

> Is there any possible workaround to prevent deleting cookies by GC?

Not really. When the browser decides that there are [too many cookies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3), it eats them. You cannot stop this (and being able to would be a huge security/privacy issue).

Your strategy should be to use as few cookies as possible (I don't mean using a single large one!), and to have your site used as often as possible. Also you can hint the browser which cookies should be deleted first, by distinguishing secure and non-secure cookies. There also is [a draft for a `Priority` attribute](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-priority-00) that you might want to employ.